# How to use VPN on a Ubuntu virtual machine (VPS)

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, vpn, vps, vpnc

I've installed VPNC on a VPS (running Ubuntu 14), but I lose my connection (ssh) to that VPS after starting a VPNC service on it. Moreover, that VPS has two interfaces, and after losing my connection to it, I can't connect to any of those interfaces. So, is there a way to assign the VPN to one interface, and connect (via ssh) to the VPS through the other interface?

Besides that, even though I'm not able to connect via ssh to that VPS after starting a VPNC service, I am able to use the virtual console, which the host company provides, to access the VPS. Accessing the virtual machine using that console, I've noticed that when VPNC is running, neither I can ping to anywhere, nor I can ssh to any machine on the VPN network. Is that supposed to happen?

Comment: Are you sure the VPS is actually making a connection to the VPN?  Given you are unable to ping once you start the service it sounds like while the service is starting no connection is being made.

Comment: I think so. Ifconfig shows that I have been assigned a VPN ip, and VPN server logs also show me as connected.

Comment: So are you able to ping the address of the VPN?  I assume you are also connected to the VPN on the the client that is attempting to communicate with the VPS?  The console being available is not exactly shocking given that it's a virtual server on a physical server makes sense the hypervisor client would always have provide a console

Comment: Actually, the client that I ssh to the VPS is not in the VPN. Is it a problem?  I'm trying to use vpnc on the VPS exactly because on my client I can't. Are both addresses (two interfaces) assigned to the VPN when I start it? Moreover, I can ping to ipsec gateway from both my client and the VPS.

Comment: typically if you are connecting a server to a VPN, its only going to be accessible to clients also on the VPN, that is what makes it secure.  As for both interfaces being used, that is likely a configuration problem, if you only want one to be used.

Comment: The second interface is an alias. @Ramhound, do you think it might be the cause of the problem?